# React: trying to check/uncheck checkbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox

I'm trying to make an obligatory Todo app to help with my React learning . The behavior I'm going for is multiple Todo lists, where you select a todo name and the list of todo items for that show. Select a different todo name and it's list todo items show, etc (like wunderlist/msft todo). For now it's using static json where each item has a child array.

I'm trying to check/uncheck a checkbox in order to mark the todo as done. My problem is that when a click the checkbox it doesn't update until a click away and then click back. What do I need to do to get it to update immediately?

code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/cdubone/todo-react-bootstrap?file=/src/App.js

Here's the relevant code:

The function:

```
const updateChecked = todo => {
todo.IsChecked = !todo.IsChecked;
};
```

Properties on the component:

```
onChange={() => updateChecked(todo)}
isChecked={todo.IsChecked}
```

The input in the component:

```
<input
type="checkbox"
id={props.id}
name={props.id}
value={props.title}
checked={props.isChecked}
onChange={props.onChange}
/>
```

Here's the data -

JSON:

```
const TodoData = [
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "Title": "Groceries",
        "TodoList": [
            {
                "Id": 1,
                "Title": "Apples",
                "IsChecked": false
            },
            {
                "Id": 2,
                "Title": "Oranges",
                "IsChecked": false
            },
            {
                "Id": 3,
                "Title": "Bananas",
                "IsChecked": true
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Id": 2,
        "Title": "Daily Tasks",
        "TodoList": [{
            "Id": 11,
            "Title": "Clean Kitchen",
            "IsChecked": false
        },
        {
            "Id": 12,
            "Title": "Feed Pets",
            "IsChecked": false
        },
        {
            "Id": 13,
            "Title": "Do Stuff",
            "IsChecked": false
        }]
    },
    {
        "Id": 3,
        "Title": "Hardware Store",
        "TodoList": []
    },
    {
        "Id": 4,
        "Title": "Costco",
        "TodoList": [{
            "Id": 21,
            "Title": "Diapers",
            "IsChecked": false
        },
        {
            "Id": 22,
            "Title": "Cat Food",
            "IsChecked": false
        },
        {
            "Id": 23,
            "Title": "Apples",
            "IsChecked": false
        },
        {
            "Id": 24,
            "Title": "Bananas",
            "IsChecked": false
        }]
    },
    {
        "Id": 5,
        "Title": "Work",
        "TodoList": [
            {
                "Id": 34,
                "Title": "TPS Reports",
                "IsChecked": true
            }
        ]
    }
]

export default TodoData;
```

Comment: can you create codesandbox, that would be very helpful..

Comment: Please, could you reproduce your code via [Codepen](https://codepen.io/) or something else.

Comment: Code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/cdubone/todo-react-bootstrap?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

You're mutating state directly rather than using setTodoData to update (a lot of your functions are doing this). Also, you're mapping the the todo items of off ActiveTodoList rather than the todoData which creates a big issue. In react there should only be 1 source of truth, so it would be better to instead store the index of the active list and map "todoData[activeIndex].TodoList.", than to store an instance of the active list itself. Finally, because the data is so nested, you need the list index and the todo item index passed into your update function to reference its location in todoData. Map lets you pass index as a second parameter.

Something along the lines of the below:

```
todoData[activeIndex].TodoList.map((todo, todoIndex) => {
   return (
      <div onClick={()=> yourFunction(todo, todoIndex, activeIndex)}> </div>
   )
}
```

```
yourFunction = (todo, todoIndex, listIndex) => {
   
    let newTodo = {...todo, IsChecked: !todo.IsCheck};

    setTodoData((todoData) => [
       ...todoData.slice(0,listIndex),
       {
         ...todoData[listIndex],
         TodoList: [
            ...todoData[listIndex].Todolist.slice(0,todoIndex)
            ,newTodo,
            ...todoData[listIndex].Todolist.slice(todoIndex + 1)
         ]
       },
       ...todoData.slice(listIndex + 1)
    ]
}
```

The goal is not to change things directly, but make copies to send to state. Unfortunately with a nested object it can get confusing very fast.